# How can change word `پیوست اول` to `پیوست آ` in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, arabic

How can change word `پیوست اول` to `پیوست آ` in table of contents pay attention my minimal code.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{zref-perpage}
\zmakeperpage{footnote}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc,geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
 % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % %
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{standalone}
%\includeonly{context}
 \usepackage{pxfonts}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{perpage}
\makeatletter
\def\@myharfi#1{\ifcase#1\or آ\or ب\or پ\or ت\or ث\or
    ج\or چ\or ح\or خ\or د\or ذ\or ر\or ز\or ژ\or س\or ش\or ص\or ض\or ط\or ظ\or ع\or غ\or ف\or ق\or ک\or گ\or ل\or م\or ن\or و\or هـ\or ی\else \@ctrerr\fi}
\def\myharfi#1{\expandafter\@myharfi\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\makeatother

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect  \numberline{\thechapter}#1}}{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect{\numberline{\chaptername~\tartibi{chapter} :  #1}}}}{}{}
%\fi
\patchcmd{\l@chapter}{\setlength\@tempdima{1.5em}}{\setlength\@tempdima{4.5em}}{}{}
\long\def\@subcaption#1[#2]#3{%
 \par
  \addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
   {\protect\numberline{\csname #1name\endcsname{} \csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
 \begingroup
   \@parboxrestore
    \if@minipage
      \@setminipage
    \fi
     \normalsize
   \@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #3}\par
 \endgroup}

 \renewcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
 \renewcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{1}{3em}{4.3em}}
 \renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3.3em}}
 \let\l@table\l@figure
 \let\stdl@chapter\l@chapter
 \renewcommand*{\l@chapter}[2]{\stdl@chapter{{#1}}{}}
 \makeatother

 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \usepackage{xepersian}
 \begin{document}
 \tableofcontents
 \chapter{this is first chapter}
 \chapter{this is second chapter}

   \appendix
       \renewcommand{\chaptername}{پیوست}
    \chapter{this is first appendix}

     \end{document}
```

Comment: Would the non-Persian equivalent of this question be "how do I change the label 'Appendix I' to 'Appendix A'"?

Comment: @Mike: Something like that, yes.

Comment: @MikeRenfro: Yes, but the OP never replied or gave feedback to the answer I provided to that question ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want, you can do that by defining a command `\mynumberstyle` that you use in your patched chapter command, instead of `\tartibi`.  It’s then enough to set that number style command to `\tartibi` at the beginning of the document, and to reset it to `\myharfi` when you start the appendix.

Hence all you have to do it to replace the line that begins with `\patchcmd\@chapter` by

```
\newcommand\mynumberstyle[1]{\tartibi{#1}}
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect  \numberline{\thechapter}#1}}{\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect{\numberline{\chaptername~\mynumberstyle{chapter} :  #1}}}}{}{}
```

and then, just after `\appendix`, to add

```
\renewcommand\mynumberstyle[1]{\myharfi{#1}}
```

Hope this helps.

P-S: Your example really wasn’t minimal to demonstrate what you wanted to achieve.  Most of the custom code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` wasn’t necessary at all, and you’re loading too many packages.  Please try to make the example smaller next time you ask for help, it’s nicer to people trying to assist you, and you’re also doing yourself a favour by trying to analyse exactly what you want to achieve.